# Windows make a %shortcut% like %APPDATA%

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-explorer, path, shortcuts

`%APPDATA%` (case insensitive) auto expands in windows explorer and the start menu to `C:\Users\username\AppData`. Is there a way to create one of these variables to point to wherever I want? Is it safe to do?

I want to make a shortcut like `%Myfolder%\foo\bar` which can be used anywhere in windows that accepts these `%shortcuts%`.

Comment: A registry key. You can make your own system variables if you want.  The process is well documented.  Are you stuck on a specific step?

Comment: @Ramhound just didn't know what these are called so was struggling to google - not sure where to begin

Comment: they are called System Variables, sometimes referred to as Syntax Variables, other times referred to as Environmental (System) Variables

Comment: https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-variables.html Environment variables are stored in the registry:

User Environment Variables: `HKCU\Environment` 
System Environment Variables: `HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment`.